# Why won't my cleaning script delete specified files?

Tags: windows, script, batch-file, cmd.exe

I am making a batch script that will automatically delete junk files from windows. With the exception of files that will be in use, the script won't delete files in some locations like `%WinDir%\Logs`. Here is the script I have so far:

```
@ECHO OFF
Color 1F
TITLE Windows Cleaner
ECHO.
:choice
set /P c=Do you want to run Windows Cleaner? Enter Y to run or C to cancel.
if /I "%c%" EQU "Y" goto :choice_yes
if /I "%c%" EQU "C" goto :choice_cancel
goto :choice
:choice_yes
for %%a in ("%TEMP%") do rd /s /q "%%~a"
for %%a in ("%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Cookies") do rd /s /q "%%~a"
for %%a in ("%LocalAppData%\CrashDumps") do rd /s /q "%%~a"
for %%a in ("%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Feeds Cache") do rd /s /q "%%~a"
for %%a in ("%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\DOMStore") do rd /s /q "%%~a"
for %%a in ("%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Caches") do rd /s /q "%%~a"
for %%a in ("%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer") do rd /s /q "%%~a"
for %%a in ("%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Windows\History") do rd /s /q "%%~a"
for %%a in ("%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\IE") do rd /s /q "%%~a"
for %%a in ("%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\Low\IE") do rd /s /q "%%~a"
for %%a in ("%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\Virtualized") do rd /s /q "%%~a"
for %%a in ("%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Windows\INetCookies") do rd /s /q "%%~a"
takeown /F "%WinDir%\Log"* /R /A
icacls "%WinDir%\Log"*.* /T /grant administrators:Fy
for %%a in (%WinDir%\Log") do rd /s /q "%%~a"
takeown /F "%WinDir%\Logs"* /R /A
icacls "%WinDir%\Logs"*.* /T /grant administrators:Fy
for %%a in (%WinDir%\Logs") do rd /s /q "%%~a"
takeown /F "%WinDir%\Temp"* /R /A
icacls "%WinDir%\Temp"*.* /T /grant administrators:Fy
for %%a in ("%WinDir%\Temp") do rd /s /q "%%~a"
:choice_cancel
echo Cleaning has been cancelled.
pause
exit
@ECHO OFF
```

If I understand correctly, I need to use `takeown` on system files and folders before my script can remove their contents. I am also running the script with elevated privileges. What a I missing here?

Comment: I don't get an error, the files just don't get deleted.

Comment: [Debugging your batch files](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_debugging.php)

Comment: Try again......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your batch file's syntax is incorrect.  Consider the following lines:

```
for %%a in (%WinDir%\Log") do rd /s /q "%%~a"
...
for %%a in (%WinDir%\Logs") do rd /s /q "%%~a"
```

On both of these lines you're missing the double quote before `%WinDir%`. The correct syntax is:

```
for %%a in ("%WinDir%\Log") do rd /s /q "%%~a"
...
for %%a in ("%WinDir%\Logs") do rd /s /q "%%~a"
```

Because by default the Administrators group has full access to the Logs folder, it's unnecessary to take ownership of it before attempting to delete the files it contains.

As a side note, the directory `%WinDir%\Log` is a non-standard directory.

Comment: What means "non-standard directory"?

Comment: It's not part of a default (a.k.a. "standard") Windows installation. In other words, if you have that directory, it was created by 3rd-party software.